# How to combine neo4j and elasticsearch

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, neo4j, lucene

I am developing a Question answering application and for that I need to use `neo4j` and `elasticsearch` in the same maven project. I am using `elasticsearch` to make my application more robust.
As we know that `neo4j` and `elasticsearch` works on different version of lucene, so whichever version I include in dependency, it gives an error.

Here is what I am doing:

First `elasticsearch` will index the data and the data and relationships will be stored as `graphdatabase` using `neo4j`. Then the user will input as a query, through which the data will be retrieved with the help of indexes. This data will be trigerred in `graphdatabasev` using trigger score which will be then propagated along the `graphdatabase` to find relevant results according to the user query.

Is there any way that I can integrate `neo4j` and `elasticsearch` in same maven project, or is there any other way through which these two modules can interact seperately.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out our integration page:

http://neo4j.com/developer/elastic-search/

Which has some discussion and also an example project to get you started.

http://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-elasticsearch

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. But this example shows that the index are same as nodes in graphdatabase and the indexed data is propertied of that nodes, while in my case the nodes are same as indexes. The method told in the configuration example uses the server. If I want to start both the servers of neo4j and elasticsearch from java, How to do it?